# Float is not convertible to CGFloat and CGFloat is not convertible to Float

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I have a problem with swift on XCode 6 beta 4, is driving me nuts I'm in IOS 8 developing a game and I have follow a tutorial but I get this: Float is not convertible to CGFloat and then when I recast as CGFloat I get the other. Here is the code:

```
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */


    //physics
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -5.0)


    // Bird
    var birdTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "kirby")
    birdTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
    bird.setScale(0.5)
    bird.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.35, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.6)

    bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:bird.size.height/2)
    bird.physicsBody.dynamic = true
    bird.physicsBody.allowsRotation = false

    self.addChild(bird)

    //ground
    ground.setScale(2.0)
    ground.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, ground.size.height/2)


    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width , ground.size.height))

    ground.physicsBody.dynamic = false
    self.addChild(ground)

    //pipes

    //create pipes
    //^

    //movement of the pipes
    let distanceToMove = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + 2.0 * pipeUp.texture.size().width) 

    let movePipe = SKAction.moveByX(-distanceToMove, y: CGFloat(0.0), duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01) * distanceToMove) <----- this line is the problem

}
```

What is going on, I move the line:

```
CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + 2.0 * pipeUp.texture.size().width)
```

I get the second error, then a recast:

```
Float(CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + 2.0 * pipeUp.texture.size().width))
```

or

```
Float(self.frame.size.width + 2.0 * pipeUp.texture.size().width)
```

gives me the first, so what do swift wants here, that is insane. Catch 22? Any help?

EDIT: I'm using a 13-inch mac late 2009, Intel Core 2 Duo, on mavericks OS X 10.9.4 (13E28) if any help. I saw something about the building options may affect the float types, but I do not know where are they.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be interpreted as a `CGFloat` and not as a `NSTimeInterval` as you cast and then multiply:

```
let movePipe = SKAction.moveByX(-distanceToMove, y: 0.0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01) * distanceToMove)
```

Try to multiply then cast to `NSTimeInterval`:

```
let movePipe = SKAction.moveByX(-distanceToMove, y: 0.0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01 * distanceToMove))
```

Also, as suggested already, you don't need to cast your distance. The following will work just fine:

```
let distanceToMove = self.frame.size.width + 2.0 * pipeUp.texture.size().width
```

Comment: Ha, I see it now, is still really strange. Thanks. Yes done that also.:)

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure every operand has the same type. Literals (`2.0`) have always their type inferred. In your case, I see no problem because

```
let distanceToMove: CGFloat = self.frame.size.width + 2.0 * pipeUp.texture.size().width
```

has all the operands of type `CGFloat` so there is no need to cast at all.

On the next line, again make sure to use the correct types. You don't need to cast the literals:

```
SKAction.moveByX(-distanceToMove, y: 0.0, duration: 0.01 * NSTimeInterval(distanceToMove))
```

Comment: Thanks it did not work still is complaining that 'CGFloat' is not convertible to 'Float', I have no idea why does it wants a float

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso On which line?

Comment: On this let movePipe = SKAction.moveByX(-distanceToMove, y: CGFloat(0.0), duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01) * distanceToMove), i see it need CGFloat so why it would be complaining about float, edited the code I pointed the wrong line